# C# XmlDocument.Save() adding quirky doctype

Tags: c#, xml, html

I am doing some processing of HTML (as XML). All works well, except for one small irritation: `XmlDocument.Save()` is changing `<!DOCTYPE html>` to `<!DOCTYPE html []>` and this is seen as quirky by the HTML5 validators. I could not find a way to prevent `XmlDocument.Save()` doing this. Could anyone help, please.

Here's the (minimal) C# code that illustrates the issue.

```
using System.Xml;

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    if (args.Length != 1) 
      return;

    string infile = args[0];
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(infile);
    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
      OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
      Indent = true,
        IndentChars = "   ",
    };
    // Some custom processing - TODO
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create("output.html", xws))
    {
      doc.Save(xw);
    }
  } // Main
} // class
```

Sample input HTML:

```
  &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
  &lt;html&gt;
     &lt;head&gt;
        &lt;meta charset="utf-8" /&gt;
        &lt;title&gt;Tester&lt;/title&gt;
     &lt;/head&gt;
     &lt;body&gt;
        &lt;h1&gt;Tester&lt;/h1&gt;
     &lt;/body&gt;
  &lt;/html&gt;
```

`Output.html` is identical to the input except for those extra square brackets at the end of the DOCTYPE.

Comment: I have been given a work-around at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbb1c569-e605-4226-a425-ec252500fdc9/xmldocumentsave-adding-quirky-doctype?forum=netfxbcl where I cross-posted the question. The work-around works.

Comment: You could answer your question yourself if you want.

Comment: It is a work-around and is not clean. Perhaps someone has a better solution? (I am using the work-around in the meanwhile)